# java_home error: change version of java or hadoop-env.sh file?

Tags: macos, hadoop, java-home

When installing Single Node Setup for Hadoop 2.6.0 on Mac 10.7.5, the manual http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html requires to update java_home.
Namely,

In Prepare to Start the Hadoop Cluster section, it says:

"In the distribution, edit the file conf/hadoop-env.sh to define at least JAVA_HOME to be the root of your Java installation."

I use the result of terminal query '/usr/libexec/java_home', which is
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home,
for the value of java_home.

As a result, hadoop scripts do not work due to error: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home: bad substitution.

The mistake is likely to be due to mismatch of currently installed on Mac.
My Java is 8.0_25 and the one hadoop uses is 6.0_05 (preferably from Sun). Also, this is the path of jdk and not jre, as may be needed.

Unfortunately, I have not found any java ire 1.6.x for any x for Mac OS in Oracle Java archives. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop requires jdk 1.6 or higher. For finding the location of already installed java, do the following steps.

In the linux command line type the command **which java**
This may give you a location if java is already installed and added to path.
Type *ll* 
This will give you the exact location where the java is present.

Eg:

> which java
>   /usr/bin/java
>
> ls -all /usr/bin/java
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 17 09:43 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
>
> ls -all /etc/alternatives/java
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep 17 09:43 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/java

In this case, the value of JAVA_HOME will be **/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60**

Use this value and add it in the hadoop-env.sh
Eg:
**export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60**

If jdk is not present, you have to install jdk. 
You mentioned about JRE. You should use JDK. JDK for MAC is available in oracle website.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

The installation document that you are following is of version 1.2.1 and the hadoop version that you have is 2.6.0. Use the proper installation document.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html